# How to evaluate the definite integral $\int_0^x t^{n-1}e^{-(a+bt)}dt$

Tags: definite-integrals

How to evaluate the following definite integral $\int_0^x t^{n-1}e^{-(a+bt)}dt$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a,b>0$.

Comment: Are you sure about the exponent ? $(a+b)t$ or $(a+bt)$ ?

Comment: It looks close to the definition of the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: yes it is $a+bt$ In case of gamma function the limit is from 0 to $\infty$.

Comment: What!? Are you kidding me @Litun?? (っ-●益●)っ ,︵‿

Comment: @V-Moy. How did you compose these characters ? What do they mean ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici See [here](http://fsymbols.com/all/#more). ≧◠‿●‿◠≦

Comment: Thank you so much @Litun. （‐＾▽＾‐）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y=bt$ then $t=\cfrac{y}{b}$ and $dt=\cfrac{dy}{b}$.
\begin{align}
\int_0^x t^{n-1}e^{-a}e^{-bt}\,dt
&=e^{-a}\int_0^x \left(\cfrac{y}{b}\right)^{n-1}e^{-y}\,\cfrac{dy}{b}\\
&=\frac{e^{-a}}{b^n}\int_0^xy^{n-1}e^{-y}\,dy
\end{align}
Since we cannot use gamma function, the only way is using integration by parts to yield integral by reduction formula. Let $u=y^{n-1}$, $du=(n-1)y^{n-2}$, $dv=e^{-y}\,dy$, and $v=-e^{-y}$. Then
\begin{align}
\int_0^xy^{n-1}e^{-y}\,dy&=\left.-y^{n-1}e^{-y}\right|_0^x+(n-1)\int_0^xy^{n-2}e^{-y}\,dy\\
I_n&=-x^{n-1}e^{-x}+(n-1)I_{n-1}
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
\int_0^x t^{n-1}e^{-(a+bt)}\,dt
&=\frac{e^{-a}}{b^n}\left(-x^{n-1}e^{-x}+(n-1)I_{n-1}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Check the edit. The exponent is $-(a+b t)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Please don't vote down my answer. I'll edit it.

Comment: Can it be further reduced to a simplified form?

Comment: @Litun I dunno. You may try it. Just use my derived formula.